# Bloodhound serves values but Typeahed doesn't show all of them, only some

Tags: javascript, typeahead.js, bloodhound

I've got the script below. I've noticed that the fetching of data works perfectly (verified by *console.log(response)*, showing precisely what's supposed to be fetched). However, in the list of possible options that displays, only some of them are shown. Sometime it's all of them, sometimes a few or even none. I can't see any system in it.

```
var users = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  //prefetch: { url: "/Worker/HintUser", cache: false, ttl: 15000 },
  remote: {
    wildcard: 'partial',
    rateLimitWait: 100,
    url: "/Worker/HintUser?input=partial",
    transform: function (response) { console.log(response); return response; }
  }
});

$("#remoteFetch").typeahead(
{ hint: true, highlight: true, minLength: 1 },
{ name: 'users', source: users });
```

I've tried using and skipping prefetch, not keeping the cache etc. Same result all the time. What am I doing wrong?

I've found quite a few [examples](http://jsfiddle.net/Fresh/bbzt9hcr/) showing how it's working but I fail to see the relevant difference. Or perhaps missing a nice trick they apply.

Comment: What does your typeahead initialization look like?

Comment: Sorry, it got cut off from the other post. Please view the completed version.

Comment: I would try specifying the datumTokenizer.

Comment: Please keep in mind that this tech is fairly new and the number of explanations is scarce. I'm not even sure what *datumTokenizer* does. It splits something based on a regex looking for spaces but when and why... I don't know. Would you care to suggest a simple implementation of it? Along with some explanation as to what the *datum* is and why we want to *tokenize* it, please?

Comment: I don't quite understand just how the datumTokenizer works, only that in certain instances the absence seems to have a negative effect on the results.  What does `response` look like (because that will decide on how I would implement it)?

Comment: [best explanation I've found](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/migration/0.10.0.md#tokenization-methods-must-be-provided)

Comment: At the moment, the response is an array of string like this *["donkey","monkey"]* andit shows as expected. The fold-out options to pick from, however, don't show all the elements. And sometimes they show old hints (not in the array) like this: *monkey/donkey/banana*. Please note that in the future I'd prefer to return a bunch of objects instead, in the results, but that's for another chapter.

Comment: can we continue this in chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111009/discussion-between-whipdancer-and-konrad-viltersten).